# LED Blinks "Too" Fast @ NUCLEO-H755ZI-Q

Tags: stm32, nucleo, stm32h7

Hi!

According to the [STM32H755ZI](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h755zi.html#documentation)'s manual [RM0399](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00176879-stm32h745755-and-stm32h747757-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), §9.5.6 (pg. 377), the default clock should be 64 MHz (HSI) after reset. Since the same code worked perfectly on other devices like e.g. a NUCLEO-F303K8, I expected the (red) LED to blink with 1 Hz. But, it does not. I also tried to play around with the prescaler value (`TIM2->PSC`), but that does not seem to take any effect... By the way, the LED actually blinks, but with ~7 Hz instead of the expected 1 Hz.
Seems the ISR is triggered by something else, but program execution does not reach the ISR, if I simply disable `TIM2`.

```c++
/*!*****************************************************************************
 * \file main.cpp
 * \brief
 * This program implements a very basic application that makes a LED blink with
 * 1 Hz.
 */

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stm32h755xx.h>

#define SYSTEM_CLOCK 64000000

/*!
 * \brief Configures pin PB14 ("LD3/Red LED") as digital output.
 */
static void Config_Red_Led(void) {
  RCC->AHB4ENR |= RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOBEN;
  GPIOB->MODER &= ~(0x3u << (2 * 14));
  GPIOB->MODER |= (0x1u << (2 * 14));
  GPIOB->OTYPER &= ~(0x1u << 14);
  GPIOB->ODR = ~(0x1u << 14);
}

/*!
 * \brief Configures TIM2 overflow with 10 us period.
 */
static void Config_10us_Blink_Timer(void) {
  //Enable the TIM2 clock.
  RCC->APB1LENR |= RCC_APB1LENR_TIM2EN;

  //Enable TIM2 interrupts.
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);

  //Make sure the timer's "counter" is off.
  TIM2->CR1 &= ~TIM_CR1_CEN;

  //Reset the peripheral.
  RCC->APB1LRSTR |= (RCC_APB1LRSTR_TIM2RST);
  RCC->APB1LRSTR &= ~(RCC_APB1LRSTR_TIM2RST);

  //Set the timer prescaler/autoreload timing registers.
  TIM2->PSC = SYSTEM_CLOCK / 1000000;
  TIM2->ARR = 10 - 1;

  //Send an update event to reset the timer and apply settings.
  TIM2->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;
}

/*!
 * \brief Enables the "Blink Timer", which will now fire interrupts that trigger
 * execution of the "App Loop" (--> \c TIM2_IRQHandler()).
 */
static void Run_App(void) {
  //Clear TIM2_IRQn update interrupt,
  TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;

  //Enable the hardware interrupt.
  TIM2->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE;

  //Enable the timer.
  TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
}

/*!
 * \brief Initializes any peripheral being used.
 */
static void Init(void) {
  //Disable CPU to respond to any configurable interrupt.
  __disable_irq();

  Config_Red_Led();
  Config_10us_Blink_Timer();

  //Enable CPU to respond to any configurable interrupt.
  __enable_irq();
}

/*!
 * \brief Initializes the system and runs the application.
 */
int main(void) {
  Init();

  Run_App();

  while(true);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*!
 * \brief This IRQ handler will be triggered every 10 us by the "Blink Timer".
 * This "time base" is used to blink a LED with a defined pattern.
 */
extern "C" void TIM2_IRQHandler(void) {
  //Blink the LED with a PWM signal of 1 Hz period and 50% DS.
  {
    static auto s = 0;
    if(++s >= 50000) {
      //Toggle PB14, which is the LED ("LD3/Red LED").
      GPIOB->ODR ^= (1 << 14);
      s = 0;
    }
  }

  //Clear TIM2 update interrupt flag.
    TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;

  //Power-down until next "tick"/interrupt.
  //__WFE();
}
```

If I use TIM6 instead, the frequency is ~2 Hz, and now modifying the prescaler value does matter. I.e. if I assume 128 MHz instead of the 64 MHz I get the 1 Hz LED Blinker:

```c++
/*!*****************************************************************************
 * \file main.cpp
 * \brief
 * This program implements a very basic application that makes a LED blink with
 * 1 Hz.
 */

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stm32h755xx.h>

/*!
 * \brief Configures pin PB14 ("LD3/Red LED") as digital output.
 */
static void Config_Red_Led(void) {
  RCC->AHB4ENR |= RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOBEN;
  GPIOB->MODER &= ~(0x3u << (2 * 14));
  GPIOB->MODER |= (0x1u << (2 * 14));
  GPIOB->OTYPER &= ~(0x1u << 14);
  GPIOB->ODR = ~(0x1u << 14);
}

/*!
 * \brief Configures TIM6 overflow with 10 us period.
 */
static void Config_10us_Blink_Timer(void) {
  //Enable the TIM6 clock.
  RCC->APB1LENR |= RCC_APB1LENR_TIM6EN;

  //Enable TIM6 interrupts.
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM6_DAC_IRQn);

  //Make sure the timer's "counter" is off.
  TIM6->CR1 &= ~TIM_CR1_CEN;

  //Reset the peripheral.
  RCC->APB1LRSTR |= (RCC_APB1LRSTR_TIM6RST);
  RCC->APB1LRSTR &= ~(RCC_APB1LRSTR_TIM6RST);

  //Set the timer prescaler/autoreload timing registers.
  TIM6->PSC = 128000000 / 1000000;
  TIM6->ARR = 10 - 1;

  //Send an update event to reset the timer and apply settings.
  TIM6->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;
}

/*!
 * \brief Enables the "Blink Timer", which will now fire interrupts that trigger
 * execution of the "App Loop" (--> \c TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler()).
 */
static void Run_App(void) {
  //Clear TIM6_IRQn update interrupt,
  TIM6->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;

  //Enable the hardware interrupt.
  TIM6->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE;

  //Enable the timer.
  TIM6->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
}

/*!
 * \brief Initializes any peripheral being used.
 */
static void Init(void) {
  //Disable CPU to respond to any configurable interrupt.
  __disable_irq();

  Config_Red_Led();
  Config_10us_Blink_Timer();

  //Enable CPU to respond to any configurable interrupt.
  __enable_irq();
}

/*!
 * \brief Initializes the system and runs the application.
 */
int main(void) {
  Init();

  Run_App();

  while(true);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*!
 * \brief This IRQ handler will be triggered every 10 us by the "Blink Timer".
 * This "time base" is used to blink a LED with a defined pattern.
 */
extern "C" void TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler(void) {
  //Blink the LED with a PWM signal of 1 Hz period and 50% DS.
  {
    static auto s = 0;
    if(++s >= 50000) {
      //Toggle PB14, which is the LED ("LD3/Red LED").
      GPIOB->ODR ^= (1 << 14);
      s = 0;
    }
  }

  //Clear TIM6 update interrupt flag.
  TIM6->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;

  //Power-down until next "tick"/interrupt.
  //__WFE();
}
```

Comment: This may be related: https://www.keil.com/support/docs/3928.htm

Comment: @Tagli: No, this isn't related. (I tested it - even if it also says that it relates specifically to the M3/M4 types.)

Comment: @Tagli: Well... Not so sure anymore... In the "TIM6 version" moving the "update flag clear" line to the top of the ISR actually seems to fix it!